# Symfony2 : complex many-to-many or data sheet form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.2

I have difficulty with the construction of the form in Symfony2 (v 2.2).
I need something like data sheet form with many-to-many connections. It looks complex.

**I Have such Entities in DB**:

- Game
- Fields
- Values
- Categories

**Connections between entities** ([PNG](http://miph.ru/stack/1/scheme.png)):

```
Categories <- Values -> Fields -> Game
```

Values contains FKs to Fields and Categories and has field "value" witch I need to save in my form (see below).
Fields contains FK to Games.

**Need such form**: [PNG](http://miph.ru/stack/1/form.png)

```
Game1
------------------------------------
          Field1    Field2    Field3
Category1    x         x         x
Category2    x         x         x
Category3    x         x         x

Game2
------------------------------------
          Field1    Field2    Field3
Category1    x         x         x
Category2    x         x         x
Category3    x         x         x

x - <input type='text'>
```

Every game (show only game title on page) has editable form (table view) where cols header contains Fields titles (records from Fields table) and rows headers contain Categories title (recored from Categories table). 
In table cells there are inputs fields stored in Values table that I need to save. If appropriate value exists in table Values we show its value (and update during form submit). If no, then we have to enter value and create such record in DB.

I thought:

- Custom form type Games where games are field type Collection
- Every game contains custom form type Values (or something like Categories-Values-Fields)

But in that case I even don't know how to construct in formBuilder  the list "Values" in the list "Games".

Another question is how to show only values from Categories and Fields and do not show any inputs because I don't need to change these tables.

Give me please some advices about how to construct such Form.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy one... Here is a high level view on all I would consider this problem. Not sure it won't raise some other tricky problems, but I hope it will at least give you some hints. I'm not sure you can have a FormType that will handle that all at once.

I would first create some GameType that follow how your entities are related :

- a GameType that contains a collection of FieldType
- a FieldType that contains a collection of ValueType
- a ValueType that has two fields : a text for the value and an entity for the Category

To summarize, in pseudo code :

```
GameType :
    $builder->add('fields', 'collection', array('type' => new FieldType());

FieldType :
    $builder->add('values', 'collection', array('type' => new ValueType()););

ValueType :
    $builder->add('value', 'text');
    $builder->add('category', 'entity', array('class'=>'YourBundle:Category');
```

To be able to display your form in a table fashion, I would pass to the template an array of availables categories and loop on it to show each widget in the good cell.

This solution will not allow you to add blank input fields for non-existants values. You can bypass that problem by adding factice empty values (like an empty string) in missing categories in you Field entity before creating the form with the entity.

```
// In the controller
$game = whateverYouDoToGetTheEntityFromDB();
$game->addDummyEmptyValues();
$form = $this->createForm(new GameType(), $game);
```

Another way may be to listen to the Form Event PRE_SET_DATA and add the missing data there.

With this solution, you may get Value entity with empty value if the user don't enter something in the field. You can delete them in a PRE_SUBMIT (called PRE_BIND in v2.0) event listener (see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653294/remove-null-values-coming-from-empty-collection-form-item/17671019#17671019)).

For your second question (non-editable display), it should be easier : try to implement the above loop but instead of showing form widget, show the entities attributes. You may start by this first view to get the table working and then try to implement the form with this working basis.