# Symfony2 Form Collection allow_add and allow_delete null error (Silex)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

I've run into a problem when following the Symfony cookbook for form collections with add/remove. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Now, for some reason, if I dynamically add a form row **but don't fill in any of its fields**, I get the following error:

`ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Project::addTask() must be an instance of Task, null given in D:\web_workspace\wedding\src\testapp.php line 82`

I would like people to be able to have blank rows in the form which will just get ignored. For example, if you click "Add Task" a few times, but don't fill in the last row, the form should still be submitted, and the last row should be ignored.

I've created a very simple Silex demo that fits in just a couple of files. I'll highlight it here, but the full example is here, and can be run by just adding Silex via composer: https://gist.github.com/mattsnowboard/7065865

I have the following Models (just `Project` which has a description and a collection of `Task`s)

```
class Task
{
    protected $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

class Project
{
    protected $description;

    protected $tasks;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tasks = array();
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTasks()
    {
        return $this->tasks;
    }
    public function addTask(Task $task)
    {
        if (!is_null($task) && !in_array($task, $this->tasks)) {
            $this->tasks[] = $task;
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeTask(Task $task)
    {
        if (!is_null($task)) {
            $this->tasks = array_diff($this->tasks, array($task));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

My forms are as follows

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
            'required' => false
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '\Task',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'task';
    }
}

class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('description', 'text', array())
            ->add('tasks', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TaskType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '\Project',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'project';
    }
}
```

The controller adds some test data to the form and just prints the data when it is submitted:

```
$app->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $project = new Project();

    // dummy code
    $task1 = new Task();
    $task1->setName('A Task');
    $project->addTask($task1);
    // end dummy code

    $form = $app['form.factory']->create(new ProjectType(), $project);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $debug = print_r($data, true);
        echo $debug;
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('test.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
})
->method('GET|POST');
```

The view is mostly this, and the javascript sample from the cookbook

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.description) }}

    <h3>Tags</h3>
    <ul class="tasks" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tasks.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
        {% for task in form.tasks %}
            <li>{{ form_row(task.name) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Am I just missing something? Is this a bug? I feel like this example which is very close to the cookbook should work pretty easily...

**Updated**: Removing `"allow_deleted"` doesn't actually fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I figured it out, the `collection` type shouldn't have `'required' => false`

```
    $builder->add('description', 'text', array())
        ->add('tasks', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new TaskType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'required' => false
        ))
```

Should be

```
    $builder->add('description', 'text', array())
        ->add('tasks', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new TaskType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true
        ))
```

Comment: I've exactly the same problem, but removing required forces html5 validation only. How did you fixed this?

Comment: I think `required` in a `collection` form type does a bit more in the code, but I could be wrong. I know it mainly affects adding the `required="required"` to the HTML, but you would have to dig into the code for the Form component to understand better. Did you try my solution or are you just assuming it won't work?

Comment: I'm sure it works but i have not tested it yet (i've found an opened issue on github). The real question is: will it work server-side (using a browser that doesn't support html5 or using a custom theme without adding these atributes)?

Comment: **The error is server side** (`ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Project::addTask() must be an instance of Task, null given in D:\web_workspace\wedding\src\testapp.php line 82`). So why wouldn't it work? As a test you could change the form templates to never use `required` and see if you still repro the issue.

Comment: Another option is to use empty_data: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#empty-data

Comment: @pagliuca Thanks that also explains _why_ this happens. "If `data_class` is set and **required is `true`, then `new $data_class()`**;
If `data_class` is set and **required is `false`, then `null`**;"

Comment: I really don't know how you figured this out and why this actually work but you saved me tons of hours of frustation!